# Can't find or create trash while deleting files

Tags: xfce, thunar

I was unable to remove a file anymore with thunar:

[image]

How should I create the "Trash" folder ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My trash works on xfce and here's what my directory structure looks like in `~/.local/share` which is the only place I have located a Trash folder:

```
drwx------ 4 myuser myuser 4096 Jun 18 10:12 Trash

    drwx------ 3 myuser myuser 4096 Jun 18 10:12 files
    drwx------ 2 myuser myuser 4096 Jun 18 10:12 info
```

Based on this...

```
mkdir ~/.local/share/Trash
mkdir ~/.local/share/Trash/files
mkdir ~/.local/share/Trash/info
```

and

```
chmod -R 700 ~/.local/share/Trash
```

looks right to me.

Comment: I also have `~/.local/share/Trash/expunged`. Don't know if it's really important, anyway.

Answer (score 2):

So, you're trash bin is not a regular directory, but a gvfs volume. The most likely cause is that you don't have gvfs installed. See https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Thunar#GVFS_and_trash_issue. Replace the `pacman` command with your distribution's package manager.